# Python - как получить строку из файла с удалением и положить ее в конец файла?

Tags: python

Собственно вопрос в чем?
Есть текстовый файл с аккаунтами:
логин1:пароль
логин2:пароль
логин3:пароль

Мне нужно взять первую строку с удалением записать в переменную и записать в конец файла.
Как это все можно реализовать за один проход открытия файла и как это еще можно сделать в многопотоке чтобы каждый поток не брал одну и ту же строку?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого и придумали базы данных, чтобы можно было в произвольном месте что-то удалить, что-то вставить (ну, не только для этого, но в том числе). Дописать в конец файла не проблема - режим открытия файла `a`. А вот удалить что-то не из конца файла - это проблема, придётся переписывать весь файл.

Т.е. делать примерно так:

- сначала прочитать все строки из файла в список, открыв файл в режиме `r` либо `r+`
- удалить нужный элемент из списка (можно сделать в процессе чтения)
- добавить элемент в нужное место списка
- записать файл, причём лучше всего открыв файл заново в режиме `w`, либо перейдя на нулевую позицию `seek(0)` и произведя его "усечение" `truncate(0)` (если открывали в режиме `r+`)

Если файл не "усекать", то в случае если добавляемая строка будет короче удаляемой, у вас в конце файла будет мусорный "хвост" от предыдущей версии файла.

Что касается многопоточности, то опять же нормально будет работать только в режиме, когда к файлу одномоментно доступается только один поток.

В общем, если у вас реально есть потребность, чтобы некий список обрабатывало много потоков, то обратите внимание на те базы данных, которые позволяют многопоточную работу с ними (простейшие БД могут не обеспечивать многопоточную работу).

Либо можете работать со списком в памяти, у питона есть специальные типы данных (например, `multiprocessing.Manager` предоставляет возможность работы с разделяемыми списками, словарями и т.д.), с которыми можно работать многопоточно, а в файл, если это нужно, пусть эти данные периодически сбрасывает один специально выделенный для этого поток.

Comment: Спасибо @CrazyElf за подробный ответ, попробую посмотреть в сторону multiprocessing.Manager